# Loop Counting in Java

Tags: java

What I have is a program that prints out 4000+ random digits in the range of 1 to 99999. After printing, it shows the range, and a couple of other things, and then asks user for 5 numbers to be input and tells how many times it had to run the loop, but I'm getting an exception in main upon print, it's coming from the main for loop. Screenshot is attached. Desired should look something like:

(Randomly generated numbers):

25

192

33

(User Enters) Please enter number: 33

(System Response) It took 3 times to find the number.

If the number is not listed, as it is over 4000 integers, it will say, not found.

Here is code and screenshot:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cd7J.png)
     Exception in Main java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:0

Thank You!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] input = new int[0];
    int[] arrayone = new int[4096];

    int loop = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < arrayone.length; i++) {
        arrayone[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 99999 + 1);

        for(int in = 0; in<input.length; in++) {
            if (arrayone[i] == input[in]) {
                loop++;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number between " + min + " and " + max);
        input[0] = s.nextInt();

        if (min <= input[0] && input[0] <= max) {
            System.out.println("It took " + loop + " time(s) to find the number " + input);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: it's always helpful to post what exception you are getting...

Comment: `int[] input = new int[0];` your array has length 0, so when you call `input[0] = s.nextInt();` it cannot assign value to first element. try to give it a proper size

Comment: Thank you for the hint, how can I change this line so that is not preassigned?

Comment: Can switch away from arrays to Lists and other collections. Much easier to deal with than arrays.

Comment: I would just like to know where I have gone wrong that I am getting an error, and as the above comment suggested, how to edit the line of int[] input = new int[0]; so that it is not already assigned.

Comment: well why does the `input` variable need to be an array? why don't you just assigna s `int input;` and then instead of `input[0] = s.nextInt();` you can do `input = s.nextInt();` Doesn't really look like it needs to be an array to me. Otherwise if you need to keep track, and you know how big the input is supposed to be declare it right away such as `int input = new int[5];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your input array is that you initialize it with a size of 0, so when you try to access the first location [0], you run out of the bounds since your array has a size of 0. In your answer you were also trying to determine the loops before asking the question. While doing this you were also trying go past the bounds of your input array with a size 0. What you should do is initialize your array of numbers first then for each guess loop through and determine if it's within the bounds of your max and min. Also note that just because the numbers are within the max and min doesn't guarantee the number is contained in the array because the numbers are not going to be sequential from max to min. You should check where you end up after your for-loop check for the input.

```
public static void main(String random[])
{
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    int input = new int[5];
    int[] arrayone = new int[4096];

    int loop = 0;

    //don't do anything here except fill the array with values
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayone.length; i++) {
        arrayone[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 99999 + 1);
    }

    //ask the user for 5 inputs
    for (int index = 0; index < input.length; index++) {

        System.out.println("Please enter a number between " + min + " and " + max);
        input[index] = s.nextInt();
        //check to see if the number is valid
        if (min <= input[index] && input[index] <= max) {
            //loop through the arrayone to determine where it is
            for(int i = 0; i < arrayone.length; i++) {
                //if it is not in the current index at i increment the loop count
                if (arrayone[i] != input[index]) {
                    loop++;
                }
                //we have found where it is and should break out of the loop
                else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            //check if we found it based on how much we incremented
            if(i != arrayone.length)
            {
                //output how long it took to find the number
                System.out.println("It took " + loop + " time(s) to find the number " + input[index]);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(input[index] + " not found!");
            }
            //now reinitialize the loop to 0 for the next guess
            loop = 0;
        }   
    }
    //always remember to close your scanners
    s.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] input = new int[0];
```

This creates an array with size of 0, so when you try save value it throws an exception because you are exceeding array size.

**Solution:** set valid size of array or use list.

The `ArrayList` is (simplifying) resizeable version of array. Use it like this:

```
List<Integer> input = new ArrayList<>();
input.add(5); //Adds 5 to list
input.get(0); //Read object of index 0

for(int value : list) { //Loop: for each element in list ...
    System.out.println(value);
}

//Checks whether list contains 5
System.out.println(list.contains(5));
```

Also, do you actually need `input` to be an array? Because right now it looks like you don't need it at all.